# Is $\# \text{Hom}(K, \mathbb{C}_p)=[K: \mathbb{Q}_p]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{C}$=complex numbers.

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $\mathbb{C}_p=\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$=$p$-adic complex numbers.

We know:

> The number of field homomorphisms $F \to \mathbb{C}$(or $\bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$) is equal to the degree of extension $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$.

**Question:**

Does the same hold for $p$-adic case ?

i.e., Is the number of field homomorphisms $K \to \mathbb{C}_p.$ equal to the degree of extension $[K: \mathbb{Q}_p]$ ?

Any comments please.

Comment: You might want to specify what you expect the field homomorphisms $K\to\mathbb C_p$ to satisfy. As I read the question they should be $\mathbb Q_p$-homomorphisms. *leoli1* seems to have interpreted them to only be $\mathbb Q$-homomorphisms.

Comment: Moreover, why going up to $\mathbb C_p$? For the analogy to holds shouldn't it suffices to consider $\overline{\mathbb Q}_p$? Any reason to bring in the topological structure?

Comment: @mrtaurho, at first both $K$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$ are vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So the field homomorphism should be $\mathbb{Q}_p$-linear.

Comment: @mrtaurho, second, no reason to bring topological structure. We can just treat the field homomorphisms $K \to \bar{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ also

Comment: Three answers and they are all right, because the question is ambiguous: mrtaurho shows the answer is yes if you mean the field homs in $Hom_{\color{red}{\mathbb Q_p}}(K, \mathbb C_p)$, leoli1 shows the answer is no if you mean the field homs in $Hom_{\color{red}{\mathbb Q}}(K, \mathbb C_p)$, and user960686 points out the difference and one way to bridge it.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thanks a lot for nice explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Recall that the *separable degree* $[L:K]_s$ of a finite algebraic field extension $L/K$ is defined as

$$
[L:K]_s=|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\overline K)|
$$

for some fixed algebraic closure $\overline K$ of $K$. Moreover, we have $[L:K]=[L:K]_s$ iff $L/K$ is separable.

Since $\mathbb Q_p$ is of characteristic $0$ it is a perfect field implying that all field extensions are separable. This entails that $[K:\mathbb Q_p]=|\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb Q_p}(K,\mathbb C_p)|$ as desired.

Comment: Seeing *user960686*'s answer I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Any comments are welcome!

Comment: It looks fine to me. But @user960686 says not any field homomorphism is $\mathbb{Q}_p$-linear. I don't know, does this affect or not

Comment: @Why I'm not completely sure what is meant by this either. The separable degree only considers $\mathbb Q_p$-linear homomorphisms to begin with...

Comment: I think your proof is correct because @user960686 is treating more general case $\Omega=\widehat{\overline{K}}$.

Comment: User960686' answer agrees with this one, and in the last paragraph just points out why leoli1's answer is different. See my comment to the question.

Answer (score 3):

More generally if $K$ is a field and $\Omega$ is an algebraically closed field extension of $K$, then for any separable finite extension $L$ of $K$, the number of $K$-algebra homomorphisms $L \to \Omega$ satisfies $|\mathrm{Hom}_K(L,\Omega)|=[L:K]$. Note that in the p-adic case, not any field homomorphism $L \to \Omega$ is necessarily $\Bbb Q_p$-linear, though. However, if we require the homomorphism to be continuous, then it is $\Bbb Q_p$-linear (the argument uses that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb Q_p$).

Comment: Thanks. Is the proof $\text{Hom}_{K}(L: \Omega)=[L:K]$ same to that of $\mathbb{Q}$, $F$ and $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @Why: I learnt that as one of the equivalent definitions of a *separable* field extension (and the equivalence to other definitions was proven) in my undergraduate algebra class.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, thanks for remembering the fact to me

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. There is a subfield $F\ne\Bbb Q$ of $\Bbb Q_p$ such that $F$ is finite and normal over $\Bbb Q$. Thus $F$ has a non-trivial automorphism. This extends to a field homomorphism $K\to\Bbb C_p$ wich is not the identity on $\Bbb Q_p$, hence $\#\operatorname{Hom}(K,\Bbb C_p)\geq\#\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Q_p}(K,\Bbb C_p)+1=[K:\Bbb Q_p]+1$

Comment: Such a field $F$ can be found using e.g. Hensel's lemma which implies that $\Bbb Q_p$ contains certain square roots of elements of $\Bbb Q$. If one wants to avoid this one can also choose a transcendence base $B=\{t_1,t_2\}\cup\{t_i\}_{i}$ of $\Bbb Q_p$ over $\Bbb Q$, then consider the isomorphism $\Bbb Q(B)\to\Bbb Q(B)$ given by $t_1\mapsto t_2,t_2\mapsto t_1$ and $t_i\mapsto t_i$ for $i\ne1,2$. This will then also extend to a homomorphism $K\to\Bbb C_p$. Of course everything here is very uncanonical and relies on AC.